# Строчная или прописная в диалоге?

Tags: прописная-строчная

"— Быстро в кузов! — Крикнул он."
Корректор в слове "крикнул" исправила прописную на строчную. А почему? Ведь, по идее, после восклицательного знака, как и после точки, должна быть прописная.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Слова автора, стоящие после прямой речи, пишутся с маленькой буквы. Такое правило. Почему? Может, потому, что предложение с прямой речью представляют особый вид сложного предложения, прямая речь и слова автора как бы части этого предложения.

Comment: Довалю.
При этом, правда, оговаривается, что слова автора должны относиться к речи персонажа или составлять с нии единое смымловое целое.  
В нашем случае это так. А правило о заглавных после точек и прочих закрывающих предложения знаков не распространяются на знаки перед закрывающей кавычкой. Прямая речь обычно заковычивается, это подразумевается и в тех случаях, когда в диалоге персонажей кавычки опускаются, при типографском, например, наборе.